# Update react native listview on child changed event firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to build a react native listview with firebase that automatically updates and re renders the list when data changes.

I run my queries in componentDidMount

```
async componentDidMount(){

 let userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('workUserId')

this.chatIdRef.child(userId).orderByChild('timeStamp').on('child_added', snap => {
this.chatsRef.child(snap.key).on('value', snapshot => {
      this.handleEvent("child_added", snap.val().userId, snapshot.val().text, snap.val().userName, snap.key);
  });
});

this.chatIdRef.child(userId).orderByChild('timeStamp').on('child_changed', snap => {
  this.chatsRef.child(snap.key).on('value', snapshot => {
      this.handleEvent("child_changed", snap.val().userId, snapshot.val().text, snap.val().userName, snap.key);
    });
  });
}
```

And then use a case to either run a child added event or child changed

```
handleEvent(event, receiverId, text, name, key) {
switch (event) {
case "child_added":
  this.items.push({event: event, receiverId: receiverId, text: text, name: name, key: key})
  this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.items)
  });
break;

case "child_changed":
  this.items.push({event: event, receiverId: receiverId, text: text, name: name, key: key})
  this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.items)
  });
break;
}}
```

When I change data in firebase the listview doesn't update accordingly, it only adds another row. I am not sure if my problem is with react native or optimizing how I run my firebase queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will add new row only, as you have not updated value. You are just pushing element into array so it will add element not update existing one.

You need to change code of `case "child_changed"` like:

```
let newArray = oldArray.slice();
newArray[indexToUpdate] = {
  ...oldArray[indexToUpdate],
  field: newValue,
};
let newDataSource = oldDataSource.cloneWithRows(newArray);
```

You can read more about this from [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4104)